# Prototype with Apps Script and then move to Market Place app. Code re-usability?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace

I am wondering about a Marketplace App to perform maintenance on Google Drive data, however as this involves architectural requirements (authentication steps, blabla), I was wondering if it could be possible at the moment just to start prototype coding a simple Apps script and test before event attempting to make the switch to the marketplace App.

I imagine that there are some differences for code running as an App script or a Market place App (client side, server side), however is there a sort of code re-usability when migrating an App script to a Market place App?

Does this idea makes sense, or is it just better to start from scratch writing a Marketplace App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I migrated a standalone Apps Script to a Marketplace App, and the only thing I had to change was the method for creating a menu (my App is a Google Sheets add-on). You may have to make a few more adjustments for authentication than I did, but you can definitely prototype in a simple Apps Script.